# How can I display error messages and confirmation messages on top of my html forms?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Can anyone here help me to display messages i.e. error messages, successful message sent confirmation in forms?

I have two forms in my HTML template which are reservations and contact. I want to display the messages like this

**reservation form :**

[image]

For your convenience I have uploaded the whole project in here [Full project](http://www.4shared.com/zip/DxG1heMhce/Restaurant-master.html)

Comment: Since you brought it up, you shouldn't have uploaded the entire project **for our convenience**. It would have been ***a lot more convenient*** if you created a [mcve] of your issue. Also, please note this is not a website where you can request free code. It's a website where you post what you tried and we tell you what's wrong with it until you are able to fix it by yourself. It's a place to learn, not a place to get work done for free.

Comment: Along with not knowing what we are working with I can suggest that where you want the error message to display create if($error){echo($error);} and then make it when ever the forum has gone through the post and see if there is an error then write $error = "Error post not made";

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a div on the position where you want to show the message and then hide it by default. Whenever you have the message to show, just append the message in the div using javascript and make the div visible. If you are using bootstrap, there are bootstrap alerts which you can use. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp